# Ways to reduce the latency achieved on my Virtual Machine in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual, latency

does anyone have any ways in which I could reduce the latency for my Azure WM (in-managed disk)? I currently have one running on the UK South area which is running at an average of 2.85m/s which is fantastic compared to the 16m/s I was receiving using my on-premises system.

However, if possible, I'd like to have this even lower, preferably down to 0.5m/s. Does anyone have any ways in which I could achieve this in the most cost-effective manner

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to get 0.5ms you need to be in the range of, like, 50-60km (máximum) from the VM. Because physics, you know?

Having said that, the only way to reduce latency is use Express Route, but it probably wont help given you have <3ms latency already.

Comment: I understand. The Express Route, this an Azure feature? I'll mark your answer anyway, Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Comment: yes, this is an Azure feature. Basically you buy a direct route (and MB\s reserve) to Azure from your ISP. It can be costly.

Answer (score 1):

Azure VM size could effect latency. Different vm sizes have different bandwidth.

You could check this [blog](https://azure-in-action.blog/2017/01/01/azure-vm-network-bandwidth-tests/).

[image]

Comment: Based on my knowledge, Express Route is expensive. What VM size do you use? If possible, I suggest you could use a larger size and test again.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I use the following
**vCPU**: 1
**GB**: 1
**Data Disks**:2
**MAX IOPS**:800
**Storage"": 2GB Local SSD.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @user8709679 If possible, I suggest you could try to use A4 series VM, it could reduce your latency.

Comment: @user8709679 I think my answer is a better answer for you.